# Is there any way to mangae large number of (600+) if condition

Tags: php

I need to compare a PHP variable with 600+ static value.

For example,
$validpostcode is a variable. and there are 600+ valid postcodes.

Now I need to check if $validpostcode is present in the list of postcodes.
What is the best way to compare?

Comment: Definitely `in_array()`

Comment: You could store the postcodes in MySQL table and query

Comment: I'm guessing postcodes doesn't change very often, and you do this quite often on your page, and if so Tristan has the right idea, store the postcodes in a database, and check for existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the postcodes as an array, you can use the in_array method, like so:

```
$postcodes = array( // Postcodes here );
$validpostcode = "POSTCODE";

if(in_array($validpostcode, $postcodes)){
    //Postcode is in the array
}
```

Good luck!

Also yeah, if you have to write the postcodes each time, then store them in a Database and use a MYSQL query to grab them all in to an array first, and then use the above methods.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I have postcode list in CSV format, I just converted them into an array and it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I can think of is to use `isset()`. Sure you can use `in_array` and `array_intersect` But they are heavier than just checking if a key is there.

Here you go:

```
$codes = array_fill_keys(array('code1', 'code2'), 0);
$tocheck = 'code1';
if (isset($codes[$tocheck])) {
      echo 'valid';
} else {
      echo 'nope';
}
```

Reference for execution time test comparison: [Faster array lookup](http://nickology.com/2012/07/03/php-faster-array-lookup-than-using-in_array/)